# How to display array value vertically in table based on key using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

I have a table which display list of item names, its classes, item quantities in each class, and total quantity of item for all items. The expected result should look like this:

```
Item Name | Item Class | Item Quantity | Total Quantity
          |      1     |       4       |
     A    |      2     |       5       |       11
          |      3     |       2       |
-------------------------------------------------------
          |      1     |       6       |
     B    |      2     |       3       |        10
          |      3     |       1       |
```

but what I got is like this:

```
Item Name | Item Class | Item Quantity | Total Quantity
          |      1     |       4       |
     A    |      2     |       5       |
          |      3     |       2       |
----------------------------------------
          |      1     |       6       |
     B    |      2     |       3       |
          |      3     |       1       | 11 | 10
```

How to display the total quantity vertically in the same row with its key(item name) and with rowspan. I use array to display results as there are hidden calculation. My code is a bit complicated because of the calculation but lets just ignore the calculation part because it works fine. If you need to understand my calculation, you can view my previous questions from my profile. What I need to fix now is how to display the total quantity correctly.

Here is my code :

```
<table>
  <tr> 
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>Item Class</td>
    <td>Item Quantity</td>
    <td>Total Quantity</td>
  </tr>

    <?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblitem");
    $classqty=array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $item=$row['itemName'];
        $class=$row['itemClassName'];

        if(!isset($classqty[$item][$class]))
        {
        $classqty[$item][$class] = 0;
        }
        if(is_null($row['itemLocCheckOut'])){
            $classqty[$item][$class] += $row['itemQty'];
        }
        else{
            $classqty[$item][$class] -= $row['itemQty'];
        }
    }

    $sum=array();
        foreach($classqty as $k1=>$v1){
            foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2){
                if(!isset($sum[$k1])){
                $sum[$k1] = $v2;
                }
                else
                {
                $sum[$k1] += $v2;
                }
    ?>

  <tr>
     <td><?php echo $k1;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $k2;?></td>
     <td><?php echo $v2;?></td>
   <?php
       } /*close second foreach*/
      } /*close first foreach*/

    foreach($sum as $name=>$total){
   ?>
    <td><?php echo $total;?></td>

    <?php
    } /*close foreach for $sum*/
    ?>
    </tr> 
    </table>
```

P/S: Please don't suggest me to use SELECT SUM because there is no problem with my calculation and I can't simply use SUM because my code involves multiple series of calculation and the total quantity is based on the result from the calculation. My problem is just on how to display the total quantity result correctly at its place vertically.

Comment: is that your quantity is based on item name?

Comment: @AjayMakwana item quantity is based on item class and item name. but total quantity is based on item name, means sum of all item quantities irrespective of their classes.

Comment: `<tr>` tag is opened inside for loop and closed outside for loop. You need to make HTML proper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT *,SUM(IF(item_name='a',itemQuantity,0)) AS itemQuantityA,SUM(IF(item_name='b',itemQuantity,0)) AS itemQuantityB FROM tblitem
```

Using this you will directly got the sum of item A and B.

and based on your requirement you can edit or customize this query.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but there is no problem with my calculation and we can't directly sum the quantities from the database because my code involves multiple series of calculation and the data in table above is just for example. My system will involve large set of data. My problem is just on how to display the total quantity vertically and in the same row with its correct item name. Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: Have you tried putting <td><?php echo $total;?></td> into your firs foreach after completing second foreach {}.?

Comment: Yes I've tried that but it will output the total quantity repeatedly. I've tried everything but nothing seems to work :(

Answer (score 0):

The HTML needs to be corrected. Have rectified the code. Try it out

```
<table>
  <tr> 
    <td>Item Name</td>
    <td>Item Class</td>
    <td>Item Quantity</td>
    <td>Total Quantity</td>
  </tr>

    <?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblitem");
    $classqty=array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $item=$row['itemName'];
    $class=$row['itemClassName'];

    if(!isset($classqty[$item][$class]))
    {
        $classqty[$item][$class] = 0;
    }
    if(is_null($row['itemLocCheckOut'])){
        $classqty[$item][$class] += $row['itemQty'];
    }
    else{
        $classqty[$item][$class] -= $row['itemQty'];
    }
    }
?>
<tr>
<?php

    $sum=array();
    foreach($classqty as $k1=>$v1){
    ?>
        <td><?php echo $k1;?></td>
        <td>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <?php
        foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2){
        if(!isset($sum[$k1])){
            $sum[$k1] = $v2;
        }
        else
        {
            $sum[$k1] += $v2;
        }
    ?>
    <td><?php echo $k2;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $v2;?></td>
  <?php
      } /*close second foreach*/
      ?>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </td>
      <td><?php echo $sum[$k1];?></td>
      } /*close first foreach*/
    ?>
    </tr> 
    </table>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! :) but your code need to be modified a little bit

Comment: and how can I make rowspan for the total quantity so that the total quantity display once only like example shown above.

Comment: Total quantity should not get repeated as per the modifications that i made in my post. Can you post the latest output structure?

Comment: yes sure. I post the latest output structure as answer.

Comment: Did you modify anything in the code which I posted? Because the structure posted by me should work fine.

Also don't post the output as an answer rather edit your question and post it there.

Comment: Yes I modified your code a little bit because the output is out of the table since you close table </table> before open <td> for echo $sum[$k1] ..and after I modified by placing </table> after </tr>, then the output structure is correct, but still don't have rowspan

Comment: If you notice i have created 2 tables. One is the main table and another is for displaying multiple values for Item Class and Item Quantity. Did you try copying entire structure that I posted?

Comment: i've tried entire structure that you posted and its not working. anyway, thanks for your help.